# Regexp multiple match in a part of a string after a specific value

Tags: java, regex, regex-lookarounds

I need to replace some values in the properties files without touching the keys, so for the example input string, I need to replace 'old' with 'new' only in the substring after the '=' sign.

> Input:
> message.document.**old**.text=This **old **document is very **old **and will stay **old **forever

> Output
> message.document.**old**.text=This **new **document is very **new **and will stay **new **forever

Positive lookbehind (?<==).*old gives a single match "This old document is very old and will stay old" whilst the desired result is three matches 'old old old' just like the primitive expression 'old' would return if the original string is just 'This old document is very old and will stay old forever' without a key

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
(\G(?!^)|=)(.*?)\bold\b
```

And replace with `$1$2new`, see the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bO67qs/2).

*Details*:

- `(\G(?!^)|=)` - Group 1 (`$1`): either the end of the previous successful match or `=`
- `(.*?)` - Group 2 (`$2`): any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
- `\bold\b` - a whole word `old`.